# Vim netrw copy commands

Tags: vim

I have removed NerdTree for netrw and have most all of the same functionality. The 2 that I am missing I really would like to have if it is possible while in the filesystem.

1. Can I copy a file while browsing the filesystem?
2. Can I copy a directory while browsing the filesystem?

If I was to have these 2 I would have exactly the same as I had with NerdTree, only wanting to use netrw because I would know it is on all machines that I would work with without having to have NerdTree.

Thank you for your help

Comment: A [very detailed answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6264/7706) on VI stackexchange.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Mark the file you want to copy:

   ```
   mf
   ```
2. Mark its target directory:

   ```
   mt
   ```
3. Copy the file:

   ```
   mc
   ```

It looks like copying a directory isn't possible in my version.

Comment: That is a shame that such a simple action happens to be so "complicated" in Netrw